# Coding an arithmetic right shift module

Tags: verilog, digital

I want to code a 16 bit Arithmetic right shift module in verilog using dataflow modeling without using bitwise operators like >>, >>> etc. Is it possible?

Comment: What is data flow modelling? What have you tried? `>>` and `>>>` are not bitwise operators, they are shift and arithmetic shift.

Answer (score 0):

```
assign word_out = {  {16{word_in[31]}} , word_in[31:16]  };
```

This is concatenating 16 of the top bit of the word_in, with the top 16 bits of the word_in, using the replication operator {{}}.